# When the file is opening in C++ and we start reading , does the whole file load to RAM from hard disk or just a block by a block?

Tags: c++, file, hard-drive

When the file is opening in C++ and we start reading , does the whole file load to RAM from hard disk or just a block by a block ?

Comment: The file can be larger than your RAM, and you can still read it normally. So it has to be loaded in separate pieces.

Comment: Start reading about the [disk buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer) and the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You decide how much to read into RAM. When you do 'getline' or read an amount into a buffer you are moving it from disk to RAM. If the file format is 'streamable' you can work on small chunks of the file at a time and still do the entire operation. Some file formats you need to read in most of the file to do an operation which can be a problem for multiple reasons.

1. If a file must be completely loaded before processing can begin you cannot start work immediately upon getting the first few bytes. This is a completely sequential operation which is slower than processing & loading at the same time.
2. As you mentioned RAM is smaller than disk, but even if a file can fit in RAM computers are often multi-tasking these days. Having 1 process need 4 GB of RAM when the same operation can be done with a few kilobytes can cause issues for other processes on the machine.

Comment: Even if you're reading one byte at a time, C++ may be doing some buffering of the file behind the scenes.  But it will be kept to a reasonable level.

Comment: Even if the file isn't streamable, and you map it, it's still only loaded block by block. And no, that's not necessarily a sequential process as you can prefetch and overlapping IO is a also a thing.

Comment: I never meant it wasn't loaded block by block. Meant more so that whether in the end you have to load the whole file into memory is determined by how the file is formatted and what you are doing with it. You can definitely do more complicated stuff with IO on non-streamable formats but that generally is pretty specific to your use case and seemed kinda above the level I felt this question was being asked from.